# Able to send, but not receive from gmail.com within Outlook 2003 (0x800CCC0F)

Tags: gmail, microsoft-outlook-2003, pop3

In my home network, I'm able to access my @gmail.com and @otherdomain.com accounts via POP3 from Outlook 2003. When accessing from my office network, I'm not able to receive, but am able to send.

I get the following error:

> Task 'myaccount@gmail.com - Receiving'
>   reported error (0x800CCC0F) : 'The
>   connection to the server was
>   interrupted.  If this problem
>   continues, contact your server
>   administrator or Internet service
>   provider (ISP).'

The POP3 is set to 995 (using SSL), SMTP to 465 (using SSL), Logon using SPA is NOT enabled.

There is NO change I make on my system from the office to home network, except my local, internal IP address changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not be surprised if the it-department at your job has blocked it. If so there is no easy way to get round it (and potentially it could cost you your job to do so).

The only way to know for sure is to ask them.

Comment: interesting thought - wouldnt mind that... :) btw, i was able to telnet to port 995 on pop.gmail.com so maybe its something else?